# Question regarding variances in Simple Linear Regression

Tags: regression, bivariate

In a linear bivariate model, why is Var(u|x) = Var(y|x)?

Comment: because only $u$ is random component in $y$. Writing like this makes more clearer: Var(Y|X) = Var(u|X)

Answer (score 2):

In simple, one-dimensional linear regression, we have the following model, with $a$ and $b$ fixed scalars even unknown:
$$Y=aX+b+U$$ $X$ is the data/covariate, $U$ is the noise, and $Y$ is the target. So, if modeled probabilistically, $y$ has two sources of randomness: data and the noise. If we're given $x$, the variance of $y$ can be written as:
$$\operatorname{var}(Y|X)=\operatorname{var}(\underbrace{aX+b}_{c, \text{a constant given X}}+U|X)=\operatorname{var}(c+U|X)=\operatorname{var}(U|X)$$